# How to created a display which combines CheckedListBox and detailed ListView?

Tags: c#, .net, listview, checkedlistbox

I am trying to create something like this:

[image]

This [example](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/controls/lists,treesandcombos/article.php/c2203) creates view using a tabbing as spacing between entry. The flaw about it is that I might experience too long entries which I don't know how it might behave in my situation.

How can I create something similar in C#? I wanted to use ListView, but then I need a check box also, so I tried CheckedListBox, but then I can not create columns.

How can I create something that is a combination of two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what is the problem in using a `ListView` for which you enable the Checkboxes?

[ListView.CheckBoxes Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.checkboxes.aspx)

Comment: I must have missed this property. Thanks for a link. I will look into it right now.

Answer (score 5):

If you create your columns in the list view using -2 as the width, the columns will be automatically sized.

For example:

```
        listView1.View = View.Details;

        listView1.CheckBoxes = true;

        listView1.Columns.Add("Col1", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Col2", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Col3", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

        ListViewItem oItem = new ListViewItem();

        oItem.Text = "Col1 Text";
        oItem.SubItems.Add("Col2 Text");
        oItem.SubItems.Add("Col3 Text");

        listView1.Items.Add(oItem);
```